# How to efficiently count all powers of 2 in a given set of numbers in vb.net?

Tags: tips, binary, fastest-algorithm

Every integer can be expressed in powers of 2. You know this as the binary system

Assume you are given a set of `k` numbers (`0 < k < 2^n`).
You want to decide for this set whether every integer power of 2 up to `2^(n-1)` occurs at least `m` times

One example:

```
n = 7 (2^n = 128, )
k = 5
set = 
{100,
91,
88,
63,
44}
m = 3

Solution:
Consider the binary representation of the set for up to n(=7) digits:
set = {
1100100
1011011
1011000
0111111
0101100
}
sum up the columns
{3,3,3,4,3,2,2} -> result the set failed, because 2 < m
```

This is so far my best(fastest) algorithm(, written for vb.net):

```
Private Function Check(arr As Integer(), n As Integer, m as Integer) As Boolean
    For i = n - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim columnCheck = 0
        For j = 0 To arr.Length - 1
            If (arr(j) And (1 << i)) <> 0 Then columnCheck += 1
        Next
        If columnCheck < m Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

maximum size of the elements of arr need to checked before entering.

Do you have better ideas?

Comment: It seems that we don't need `n` and `k` as input because we already have a correct set of numbers

Comment: I dont have k as input. n is needed for the loop, however you can calculate this from the array. Although I dont want to do that, because im checking the different inputs not randomly, but I assume a constant n over multiple iterations. So I dont want to calculate it everytime. Assume set is generated from n not the other way around, so you know n always before u know the set.

Comment: You probably should add the [`tips`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/tips/info) tag.

Comment: Either I should or I shouldnt, I dont see probability associated with this^^

Comment: I think the relative sizes of `m`, `n`, and `k` matter a lot for performance. For instance, is `m` roughly on the scale of `k`, or is it small? Do you know in what regime you're working in?

Comment: This should be left open as [tag:tips]

Comment: you can assume `k` is small in general. if it helps you can also assume `2m -1 = k`

Comment: In that case you can use masks of the form `100010001...1, 100010001...10,...  100010001...1000` where the distance `d` between consecutive 1s is `ceil(log2(k))`. For each of the masks take the bit-wise and with all the given numbers and then sum them. Chop the binary representation of the sum up into `d` sized chunks (cutting right of each `1` in the mask) to get the counts of individual bits.

Comment: I dont understand, maybe my maths is to bad for this, can you explain it on the example given in the question?

Comment: This should be closed, I think this should be in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) instead.